Why is this React Server Component never loading when awaiting data?
I'm moving from Nuxt to NextJS and I've been playing with it for 1 month now, so I am pretty new to the framework.
I am trying to use StabilityAI-SDXL with NextJS, and it should be very straightforward. Using NextJS version 14.2.3.
Steps to reproduce my issue:

Create a project using pnpm dlx create-next-app --eslint --js. Give it a name. Use the src/ directory and App Router.

Install the replicate package using pnpm add replicate.

Create a .env.local file and set the Replicate API token: REPLICATE_API_TOKEN=r8_xyz

In the root "page.js", delete all code there. Use this instead:


import Replicate from "replicate";
const replicate = new Replicate();

const input = {
  width: 768,
  height: 768,
  prompt: "An astronaut riding a rainbow unicorn, cinematic, dramatic",
  refine: "expert_ensemble_refiner",
  apply_watermark: false,
  num_inference_steps: 25,
};

export default async function Page() {
  const output = await replicate.run(
    "stability-ai/sdxl:39ed52f2a78e934b3ba6e2a89f5b1c712de7dfea535525255b1aa35c5565e08b",
    { input }
  );
  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(output, null, 2)}</pre>;
}

Expected output:
What I expect to see is "output" getting rendered to the screen after getting the awaited data.
Actual result that I get:
What I get is a page that never ends loading, no matter how much time I wait. I don't see anything in the final html, it's like "output" is never getting set, and seems like "replicate.run" never resolves. No error or messages in the console.
I assume this is something related to NextJS and React Server Components in general. The code I've shown is a copy-paste from the "NodeJS" section of Replicate's official docs, here.
What I do know for a fact is that my API is working, and Stability AI's endpoint is getting hit, since I can see that in my Replicate's dashboard, billing section.
I must be doing something wrong in this RSC, but since I don't have much experience in NextJS I can't figure out what it is. All help will be greatly appreciated.

I guess it might be next has extended fetch function and route handler convention, inside this library still using fetch calling API. That's why the Docs has specific Nextjs guide using route handler.

It seems like using export const fetchCache = "force-no-store"; helps me avoid that issue, and half of the times I get a positive result. THe other half the page keeps loading forever. Caching is such a difficult topic in NextJS but I hope I end up mastering it.
